# Registering multiple MBeans in Liberty

Tags: jmx, websphere-liberty, java-ee-7, mbeans

I am trying to register a newly created MBean for `JMX Publisher`. Looking at the IBM#s website I can see

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import org.example.Example;


...

MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
Object mbean = new Example();
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.example.MyApplication:name=Example");
mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name);
```

**Question** How would multiple `MBeans` be registered? Should I just simply do the following for the second Bean to register?

```
Object mbean2 = new Example();
ObjectName name2 = new ObjectName("org.example.MyApplication:name=Example2");
mbs.registerMBean(mbean2, name2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to call 'registerMBean' multiple times, with unique ObjectNames.  The actual object implementation could be the same, just the ObjectName that must differ.